# argument to cp in backticks doesn't work?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, cp

I tried using a command like

```
cp `ls ~/temp/*.xyz | head -1` ./
```

But that does not work. If I echo the value of command inside back ticks and put it manually in cp command it works.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text produced by the backticks (or the alternate syntax `$(…)`), like text resulting from substituting a variable (`$foo`), is expanded by the shell: it is broken into words, and the words are interpreted as glob patterns (i.e. `\[?*` operate to match files). To avoid this issue, **always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions**.

There's a second issue: [parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea for various reasons.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

If you use zsh as your shell, an easy way to do what you're attempting is

```
cp ~/temp/*.xyz([1]) ./
```

On other shells, this is harder. On the command line, you might risk using `ls`, if you know your file doesn't contain any nonprintable character (for `ls`'s definition of nonprintable). In a script, this is calling for disaster; a simple two-liner in ksh or bash is

```
tmp=(~/temp/*.xyz)
cp -- "${a[0]}" ./
```

On other shells, you can do it this way (note that this overwrites the positional parameters):

```
set -- ~/temp/*.xyz
cp -- "$1" ./
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the matched file contains special characters (e.g. spaces) so you need to quote the back ticks expression:

```
cp "`ls ~/temp/*.xyz | head -1`" .
```